# SQL getting less/between than value from decimal (13,6)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to get a value between 0 & 10,000 for a chart i'm making
But first I need to get it work in MySQL the column is called totalExcl and type = decimal(13,6)

normaly it works when I do `AND o.total_paid_tax_excl BETWEEN (1.00) AND (10.0000)` but this does not work with decimal(13,6)

This is how my table looks like but with more results!

```
╔══════════════ ╦═════════╗
║   count       ║ lastname║
╠══════════════ ╬═════════╣
║ 798.500000    ║ Honny   ║
╚══════════════ ╩═════════╝
╠══════════════ ╬═════════╣
║ 126108.710000 ║ Bont    ║
╚══════════════ ╩═════════╝
```

I want to get a value from column name `'count'` a value between 1 & 10.000

Thanks

```
SELECT 
    SUM(o.total_paid_tax_excl) AS count,
    IFNULL(CONCAT(e.firstname, ' ', e.lastname),
            'Web order') AS lastname
FROM
    ex.ps_orders o
        LEFT JOIN
    ex.ps_oxo_quotation q ON o.id_order = q.idOrder
        LEFT JOIN
    ex.ps_employee e ON q.idEmployee = e.id_employee
WHERE
    current_state IN (3 , 4, 5, 9, 13, 15, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 121) 
GROUP BY q.idEmployee
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes.

Comment: Still getting some with values above the 10.000

Comment: @Deniz use between as `AND o.total_paid_tax_excl BETWEEN '1' AND '10000'`

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return unpredictable data with older versions... The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Seems like the (LEFT) JOIN order is a bit ad-hoc as well.

Comment: I need to use group by because of google charts otherwise it will not accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT
exe.*
FROM
(
SELECT 
    SUM(o.total_paid_tax_excl) AS count,
    IFNULL(CONCAT(e.firstname, ' ', e.lastname),
            'Web order') AS lastname
FROM
    ex.ps_orders o
        LEFT JOIN
    ex.ps_oxo_quotation q ON o.id_order = q.idOrder
        LEFT JOIN
    ex.ps_employee e ON q.idEmployee = e.id_employee
WHERE
    current_state IN (3 , 4, 5, 9, 13, 15, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 121) 
GROUP BY q.idEmployee
ORDER BY count DESC
) exe
where exe.count between 1 and 10000;
```

Comment: Still invalid GROUP BY.

Comment: If i remove GROUP BY google charts will not accept my query!

Answer (score 0):

Use **BETWEEN**

```
WHERE test_column BETWEEN
    low_value AND high_value
```

OR use Equivalent

```
WHERE (test_column >= low_value)
    AND (test_column <= high_value)
```

Between that you used should be

```
AND o.total_paid_tax_excl BETWEEN '1' AND '10000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than using a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(o.total_paid_tax_excl) AS count,
    IFNULL(CONCAT(e.firstname, ' ', e.lastname), 'Web order') AS lastname
FROM ex.ps_orders o
LEFT JOIN ex.ps_oxo_quotation q ON o.id_order = q.idOrder
LEFT JOIN ex.ps_employee e ON q.idEmployee = e.id_employee
WHERE current_state IN (3, 4, 5, 9, 13, 15, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 121) 
GROUP BY q.idEmployee
HAVING count between 1.00 and 10.000;
```

Caveat:  If `total_paid_tax_excl` is `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`, you could have roundoff issues.

What table is `current_state` in?  This could matter for designing the optimal indexes.